# Currency Exchange in Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm writing code for currency exchanger in spring boot (I'm a begginer) and right now I'm stuck on thymeleaf template. Right now my template looks like this :

```
<div align="center">
    <form th:action = "@{/postCurrency}" method = "POST">
        <label for="firstNumber"></label>
        <input id = "firstNumber" type="number" name = "fNumber"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

So this means that I have one "box" where user types in number and now I want to have a second "box" where currency will be exchanged and automatically shown in that "box", How do I do that ?

EDIT : My template now looks like this (exchange.html):

```
      <form th:action = "@{/postCurrency}" method = "POST">
        <label for="firstNumber"></label>
        <input id = "firstNumber" type="number" name = "fNumber"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type = "number" th:field="*{resultNumber}" disabled/>
    </form>
```

My controller class :

```
  @PostMapping("/postCurrency")
  public String postExchange(@RequestParam Double fNumber , Model model){
    Double number = exchangeLogic.exchange(fNumber);
    model.addAttribute("resultNumber",number);
    return "redirect:/exchange";
}
```

The problem is that thymleaf can't read the modelattribute , I need to take "resultNumber" and make it visible in form tag

Comment: You should really read a bit about thymeleaf. What you're asking is fairly basic. Check this: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html There's a pretty good example with a working application

Comment: I took a look but still no idea, can you help me out ? I edited my code @CrazySabbath

Comment: It's basic, but me too I am a beginner and such troubles I fall into often. This question is useful to me.

Comment: What do you want to do actually? Do you want to see the exchanged value just after typing your number or just after your post call?

Comment: Actually knowing both ways would be usefull , Just after typing number and also after pressing submit button. @Aritra Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller try this.

```
   @PostMapping("/postCurrency")
  public String postExchange(@RequestParam Double fNumber , Model model){
    Double number = exchangeLogic.exchange(fNumber);
    model.addAttribute("resultNumber",number);
    return "exchange";//your html page
}
```

and in your html page

```
<input type = "number" th:value="${resultNumber}" disabled/>
```

let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Huh, it does work now, but I already tried this and it didn't work. I guess the problem was that I had - return "redirect:/exchange" <- this didn't let the thymeleaf template to grab the modelattribute because it reloaded page (I guess). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `return "redirect:/exchange"` will never work as it reloads the page. that's why I changed your return type of your method. And if you want to get your exchange value before post call you have to use JS.

Comment: oh, ok , Thank you very much